# Ionic start command bypassing ssl verification

Tags: ionic-framework, command-line-interface

How to bypass ssl certificate verification for ionic start command ?

**Below is the CLI message what i get while i run the ionic start command**

```
mca@mca-hp-88:~/ionsam$ ionic start app
? What starter would you like to use: blank
✔ Creating directory ./app - done!
[INFO] Fetching app base
       (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
✖ Downloading - failed!
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

**I want to bypass ssl verification and i dont want to set proxy.**

Comment: did you try `ionic start app blank`

Comment: **I tried that alse still the same error occurs.**

Comment: which ionic version do you have?

Comment: i am using ionic v 3.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your support, i found a way to bypass the ssl verification.
By Adding a variable to the environment we can bypass the ssl verification for ionic start command.

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

**This is only a TEMPORARY solution**

Answer (score 0):

try this

harish> ionic start app blank

harish> ionic serve

Comment: mca@mca-hp-88:~/ionsam$ ionic start app blank
[INFO] The Ionic CLI has an update available (3.6.0 => 3.9.2)!

[WARN] No write permissions for global node_modules--automatic CLI updates are
       disabled.
       To fix, see https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions
       
       Or, install the CLI update manually:
       
       npm install -g ionic@latest
       
[INFO] Fetching app base
       (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
✖ Downloading - failed!
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain